# PHP OpenSSL - is everything lost?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I have used PHP openssl encryption on a string;

`$encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);`

However, I did not base64 encode `$simple_string` and now the encrypted output is with `/`, `+` and other special characters.

The decrypt function gives me an output with wrong special characters.

How I can decrypt even though the string has special characters?

Comment: The likelihood is that the output used padding or bytes not supported by uft8mb4. Strings in PHP are byte streams, which means if you stored the output of `openssl_encrypt` then you could later decrypt its contents without any need of encoding. If you saved its output to a database or file set to utf8mb4 etc... then no, you cannot restore its decrypted contents is the most likely answer because it no longer contains the correct bytes.

Comment: Use  [`Hello, World`](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=XOR(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'AA'%7D,'Standard',false)&input=SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk) as an example. The XOR'd output is wrongly decoded because it uses [unsupported bytes in `utf8mb4`](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=XOR(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'AA'%7D,'Standard',false)&input=4s/GxsUuLv3F2MbO). However, [the base64 encoded](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)XOR(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'AA'%7D,'Standard',false)&input=NHMvR3hzV0dpdjNGMk1iTw) output decrypts fine.

Comment: The value of `$options` controls whether the ciphertext is Base64 encoded or not, and not the encoding of the plaintext. `$options` defaults to `0`, which means that the ciphertext is Base64 encoded. When decrypting the Base64 encoded ciphertext, `$options` must also be set to `0`. For an analysis of your issue it is necessary that you share the code with the encryption and decryption including sample data, s. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).